# Letterboxing when testing in iOS Simulator using iOS 7.1 and iPhone 5s

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6

I'm having difficulty understanding why apps are being letterboxed when simulating iOS 7 on the 5 and 5s. When using iOS 8 simulation it sizes properly. What could cause this? I don't have the 7.1 SDK on my computer, but I was told I didn't need it if using Swift (although I still get the problem on another computer when using the Xcode 7.1 SDK with Objective C and Xcode 6).

The picture below shows a default master detail application with zero lines of custom code written. The only thing that is changed is the development target (to iOS 7.1). I've checked the constraints on the views in the storyboard, and everything checks out.

[image: iPhone 5s letterboxed]

Comment: I tried it in Xcode 6.0.1 and could not reproduce the problem. Have you tried create a bland new project and see how it goes?

Comment: This is a brand new project. It's just a simple master detail application. Doesn't make any sense. Ha.

Comment: Letterboxing is related to the presence/absence of a "-568h@2x" launch image, as far as I know. Also, launch images work a bit different between iOS 7 and iOS 8. In iOS 8, you can setup a xib/storyboard for its view to work as "launch image". Hope this helps somehow...

Comment: I saw the "App not sized properly" one, but I failed to see how it's the same as this because I'm not trying to load launch images. This is a table view. Are you saying if I put a "-568h@2x" launch image in my assets even if I don't use it the application will magically work as it should? I should reiterate here this is a 100% Xcode generated master detail application. I've written 0 lines of code.

Comment: Yes, this is known issue. see: http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.1_gm_seed/xcode_6.1_gm_seed_release_notes.pdf p.19

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. I'll do that. If you'd like you can post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't know the actual issue, but I do know that the OS determines if the app is "4 inch ready" (and therefore, shouldn't be letterboxed at runtime) by checking the existence of a 4-inch launch image (e.g., 640 x 1136) among the resources.